# How to improve appearance of a decision tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting

I am new to creating graphics (in this case a decision tree) in latex. I have figured out how to draw the tree I need, but I could use a little help making it look nicer. Specifically, I would like to make the text labels (e.g. None/Some/Full/No/Yes) be oriented parallel to the path they label. Below is my code and an image of my tree. I have placed red arrows on the tree showing how I would like the different text labels oriented. Thanks for your help!

```
\documentclass[12pt, fullpage,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    Patrons/.style = {text = black, label = center:\textsf{Patrons}},
    Friday/.style = {text = black, label = center:\textsf{Friday}},
    Hungry/.style = {text = black, label = center:\textsf{Hungry}},
    No/.style = {text = black, label = center:\textsf{No}},
    Yes/.style = {text = black, label = center:\textsf{Yes}}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale = 1, transform shape, thick,
    every node/.style = {draw, rectangle, minimum size = 15mm},
    grow = down, 
    level 1/.style = {sibling distance=4cm},
    level 2/.style = {sibling distance=4cm}, 
    level 3/.style = {sibling distance=2cm}, 
    level distance = 3cm
    ]
  
  \node [Patrons] (A) {}
  child { node [No] (B) {}} 
  child { node [Yes] (C) {}}
  child { node [Friday] (D) {}
    child { node [Hungry] (E) {}
        child { node [No] (G) {}}
        child { node [Yes] (H) {}}
    }
    child { node [No] (F) {}}
  };
  
  % Labels
  \begin{scope}[nodes = {draw = none}]
    \path (A) -- (B) node [near start, left] {None};
    \path (A) -- (C) node [near start, left] {Some};
    \path (A) -- (D) node [near start, right] {Full};
    \path (D) -- (E) node [near start, left] {Yes};
    \path (E) -- (F) node [near start, left] {No};
    \path (E) -- (G) node [near start, right] {Yes};
    \path (D) -- (H) node [near start, right] {No};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: For trees consider use `forest`. There are a lot of examples in this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple style for the tree -- names only need to be filled for example--

```
child { node [P] (D) {Friday} %--- only Friday needs to be filled now
```

Thus repetition is avoided

Similarly for labels a simple style with sloped option is set -- have alook -- also the nodes in the labels section need to be placed just after the `--` and not at the end

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, fullpage,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        P/.style = {text = black, label = center:\textsf{#1}},
%       Friday/.style = {text = black, label = center:\textsf{#1}},
%       Hungry/.style = {text = black, label = center:\textsf{Hungry}},
%       No/.style = {text = black, label = center:\textsf{No}},
%       Yes/.style = {text = black, label = center:\textsf{Yes}}
    }
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale = 1, transform shape, thick,
    every node/.style = {draw, rectangle, minimum size = 15mm},
    grow = down, 
    level 1/.style = {sibling distance=4cm},
    level 2/.style = {sibling distance=4cm}, 
    level 3/.style = {sibling distance=2cm}, 
    level distance = 3cm
    ]
    
    \node [P] (A) {}
    child { node [P] (B) {}} 
    child { node [P] (C) {}}
    child { node [P] (D) {Friday}
        child { node [P] (E) {}
            child { node [P] (G) {}}
            child { node [P] (H) {}}
        }
        child { node [P] (F) {}}
    };
    
    % Labels
    \begin{scope}[nodes = {draw = none},pos=0.3, sloped,left]
    \path (A) -- node [yshift=5pt] {None} (B) ;
%   \path (A) -- (C) node [] {Some};
%   \path (A) -- (D) node [] {Full};
%   \path (D) -- (E) node [] {Yes};
%   \path (E) -- (F) node [] {No};
%   \path (E) -- (G) node [] {Yes};
%   \path (D) -- (H) node [] {No};
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help.